# Full GC does not fully recover memory

Tags: java, memory, jboss, garbage-collection, jvm

here is the jvm settings for Jboss AS 7 / EAP 6

```
java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode)


VM Arguments: -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat 
-XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:E:\serverLog\jvm.log
-Xms1303M -Xmx1303M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M 
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true 
-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman 
-Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=E:\JAVA
\JBOSS\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0\standalone\log\boot.log 
-Dlogging.configuration=file:E:\JAVA\JBOSS\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0
\standalone/configuration/logging.properties
```

I made several heavy-loading pages refresh every 30s, then I found in gc log, there are gradually frequent full garbage collection occurs, each full GC release part of the old generation but it getting smaller and smaller and finally just get overhead, [here](http://jpst.it/yEQ1) is the jvm log

I wonder whether this indicates a memory leak or a jvm tune up matter and how to get the full gc recover most of the memory each time?

## UPDATE

Thanks everyone for the guideline, after retrieve heap dump and analyze with Eclipse MAT, it looks all the leaking coming from **org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer**

here are screenshots of the results

800+m memory leak

[image]

[image]

## UPDATE 2

I don't know if it is the same issue but I tried to apply the same changes from another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234975/jstl-foreach-tag-in-jboss-7-memory-leak), I can see the application use less memory but the leak is still there. the full GC only recover small amount of tenured generation hence(well young generate leaked anyway) so after several full gc the server got its overhead...

Comment: @brso05 thanks could you please elaborate a little? :)

Comment: Likely a leak. Take hprof memory dump via jmap, then analyze them via Eclipse Memory Analyzer or another tool. Sometimes it's good to take the second dump after a while and compare them.

Comment: Full GC can happen when there's a region resize as well but looking at your logs, Full GC is happening because Old gen is filling up fast and even after GC, memory freed in Old gen is not big, so like others said it's mostly a memory leak :) I think you're retaining big objects for longer duration, hence Full GC is not able to free significant memory

Comment: not directly related to your question, but you do know that java 1.6 has long reached EOL, right?

Comment: thanks I have update the post with Eclipse MAT result, please share any advice.

Comment: @the8472 yes..JDK 6 is old school.. but it is part of the requirement....

Comment: It is strange, that MAT claims that org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer occupies almost 900MB, but on your second screenshot the retained size of it is only 1MB. Can you find that ConcurrentReferenceHashMap that MAT mentions and peek inside it?

Comment: On a side note: you can try http://plumbr.eu tool for memory leak root cause analysis. Full disclosure: I am one of the authors :)